# How can I forbid non admins from posting stories to my Facebook groups?

Tags: facebook-groups

Apparently Facebook added a new feature to Facebook groups, Facebook groups stories, and somehow regular users are featuring stories to the groups I'm admin of without my permission. How can I forbid non admins from posting stories to my Facebook groups?